# top and right FrameLabel not working for ListPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling, frame

Since upgrading to version 11.3 (Linux CentOS7 64b), FrameLabel can only provide the normal labels, to the left and below the plot, for ListPlot, however it works as it should for any other plots.

For example:

```
Plot[t, {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}]
```

[image: workingExample]

```
ListPlot[Table[t, {t, 0, 10}], Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}]
```

[image: nonWorkingExample]

As you can see, labels "c" and "d" are present in the Plot[] but not in the ListPlot[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form `FrameLabel -> {{leftlabel, rightlabel}, {bottomlabel, toplabel}}`:

```
ListPlot[Table[t, {t, 0, 10}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"b", "d"}, {"a", "c"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, like that it works. Nevertheless, in all my old scripts (lots of them), I always did it like FrameLabel -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"} and never had an issue. Also, this "incorrect" form still works for other types of plots than ListPlot[].

Comment: @bjorn, i am not 100 pct sure, but that form seems to have disappeared from the docs (probably being deprecated).